# Lightning : Unable to update records displayed using wrapper class

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, wrapper-class, aura-attribute

Can anyone please help me in this?

My initial Use Case Scenario was to display a list of records in a lightning component, and providing the ability for users to update the same records. This was a simple implementation by using an aura attribute with type as list of sobject records.

But Later the ask changed to show the same records in a categorized manner, say all records of Type A must appear first, followed by all records of Type B, much like a summarized report where we create a grouping based on some field.

To achieve that, I had to create a wrapper class in my controller, and instead of using List of sObject, I had to use List of Wrapper class in my Lightning component to display the records accordingly.

The display part was over. I achieved it. Yay!

But the issue that came up was editing the records. The records were no longer updating.

For updation, On the click of Save button, I pushed the List of Wrapper back to the controller for updation. But, there is some unknown Exception firing up each time I click on Save button for updation of records in the Apex Class.

When I debug the List returned by the component from the controller, it appears to be in a suspicious format.

Can anyone please help me in an approach for updating the records. My code is as below :

Lightning Component Code :

//DocList1 is the attribute for type List of wrapper class and used to display the records.

```
<aura:attribute name="DocList1" type="DocumentListController.DocumentListWrapper[]" description="store wrapper class records list"/>
```

// Js Controller : Save is the method that runs on Save button click

```
({
initRecords: function(component, event, helper) {
    // call the apex class method and fetch sub stage of loan appliction record 
     alert('Modification in progress');
     var action = component.get("c.fetchSubStage");
     action.setParams({
                'loanId': component.get("v.recordId")
              });
         action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
          var state = response.getState();
             //alert(state);
          if (state === "SUCCESS") {
              var capturedResponse = response.getReturnValue();
              console.log('Response received'+capturedResponse);
              console.log(JSON.stringify(capturedResponse));
           // set SubStage attribute with return value from server.
              component.set("v.subStage", capturedResponse);

        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);

  // call the apex class method and fetch account list  
     var action = component.get("c.fetchDocuments");
     action.setParams({
                'loanId': component.get("v.recordId")
              });
         action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
          var state = response.getState();
             //alert(state);
          if (state === "SUCCESS") {
              var storeResponse = response.getReturnValue();
              console.log('List received'+storeResponse);
              //component.set("v.DocList", storeResponse);
              console.log(JSON.stringify(storeResponse));
           // set AccountList list with return value from server.
              component.set("v.DocList1", storeResponse);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
Save : function(component, event, helper) {
        //console.log('DocList'+component.get("v.DocList1")[0].lstDocumentCheckList[0].Id); 

        var action = component.get("c.saveLoan");
        action.setParams({
            "listOfDoc": component.get("v.DocList1")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            //alert('12121');
            if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS" && component.isValid()) {
                component.set("v.DocList1", response.getReturnValue());
                component.set("v.showSaveCancelBtn",false);
            }
            //window.location.reload(true);
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);

}
```

})

And finally the controller class goes as follows : 
//saveLoan is the method for updating the records, but the Unknown Exception is thrown in Salesforce, Right after the System.debug statement for displaying the list.

```
public class DocumentListController {
    // method for fetching the Sub Stage of the Loan Application record.
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String fetchSubStage(Id loanId) {
        String subStage;
        List<Loan_Application__c> lstLoanApplication;
        if(String.isNotBlank(loanId)) {
            lstLoanApplication = [SELECT  ID, Sub_Stage__c FROM Loan_Application__c WHERE ID = :loanId LIMIT 1];
            if(!lstLoanApplication.isEmpty()) {
                subStage = lstLoanApplication[0].Sub_Stage__c;
            }
        }
        System.debug('Debug Log for subStage'+subStage);
        return subStage;
    }

    // method for fetch account records list  
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List <DocumentListWrapper> fetchDocuments(Id loanId) {
       //Map of Contact ID to Contact Name
       Map<String, List<Document_Checklist__c>> mapContactNametoDocChecklist = new Map<String, List<Document_Checklist__c>>();
       List < Document_Checklist__c > returnList = new List < Document_Checklist__c > ();
       List < Document_Checklist__c > lstOfDoc;
       List<DocumentListWrapper> lstDocumentWrapper = new List<DocumentListWrapper>();
       List<Loan_Application__c> lstLoanApplication = [SELECT  ID, Sub_Stage__c FROM Loan_Application__c WHERE ID = :loanId LIMIT 1];
       String subStage;
       String fieldsToQuery;

       if(!lstLoanApplication.isEmpty()) {
            subStage = lstLoanApplication[0].Sub_Stage__c;
       }
       System.debug('Debug Log for subStage'+subStage);

       if(subStage == 'Application Initiation') {
            //fieldsToQuery = 'Id, Contact_Name__c, Document_Type__r.name, Document_Master__c, Document_Master__r.Name, Status__c, Original_Seen_and_Verified__c';
            fieldsToQuery = 'Id, Contact_Name__c, Document_Type__r.name, Document_Master__c, Document_Master__r.Name, Status__c, Original_Seen_and_Verified__c';
       }

       else if(subStage == 'File Check') {
            fieldsToQuery = 'Id, Contact_Name__c, Document_Type__r.name, Document_Master__c, Document_Master__r.Name, Status__c, File_Check_Completed__c';

       }

       else if(subStage == 'COPS:Data Maker') {
            fieldsToQuery = 'Id, Contact_Name__c, Document_Type__r.name, Document_Master__c, Document_Master__r.Name, Status__c, Document_Collection_Mode__c, Screened__c, Sampled__c';
       }

       else if(subStage == 'COPS:Data Checker') {
            fieldsToQuery = 'Id, Contact_Name__c, Document_Type__r.name, Document_Master__c, Document_Master__r.Name, Status__c, Document_Collection_Mode__c, Screened__c, Sampled__c';
       }

       else if(subStage == 'Scan: Data Maker') {
            //fieldsToQuery = 'Id, Contact_Name__c, Document_Type__r.name, Document_Master__c, Document_Master__r.Name, Status__c, Scan_Check_Completed__c, Document_Collection_Mode__c, Screened__c, Sampled__c';
            fieldsToQuery = 'Id, Contact_Name__c, Status__c, Scan_Check_Completed__c, Document_Collection_Mode__c, Screened__c, Sampled__c';
       }

       else if(subStage == 'Scan: Data Checker') {
            fieldsToQuery = 'Id, Contact_Name__c, Document_Type__r.name, Document_Master__c, Document_Master__r.Name, Status__c, Scan_Check_Completed__c, Document_Collection_Mode__c, Screened__c, Sampled__c';
       }

       System.debug('Debug Log for fieldsToQuery'+fieldsToQuery);
       if(String.isNotBlank(fieldsToQuery)) {
            String query = 'SELECT '+fieldsToQuery+' FROM Document_Checklist__c where Loan_Applications__c =\''+loanId+'\' ORDER BY Contact_Name__c NULLS FIRST';
            System.debug('Debug Log for query'+query);
            lstOfDoc = Database.query(query);
       }
       else {
            lstOfDoc = [select id,Contact_Name__c,Loan_Contact__r.name,Document_Type__r.name,Document_Master__c,Document_Master__r.name,Loan_Engine_Mandatory__c,Express_Queue_Mandatory__c,Status__c,Original_Seen_and_Verified__c,File_Check_Completed__c,Scan_Check_Completed__c from Document_Checklist__c where Loan_Applications__c =:loanId];
       }
       //lstOfDoc = [select id,Contact_Name__c,Loan_Contact__r.name,Document_Type__r.name,Document_Master__c,Document_Master__r.name,Loan_Engine_Mandatory__c,Express_Queue_Mandatory__c,Status__c,Original_Seen_and_Verified__c,File_Check_Completed__c,Scan_Check_Completed__c from Document_Checklist__c where Loan_Applications__c =:loanId];
        if(!lstOfDoc.isEmpty()) {
            for (Document_Checklist__c doc: lstOfDoc) {
                returnList.add(doc);
                /*System.debug('Debug Log for doc.Document_Type__r.name'+doc.Document_Type__r.name);
                System.debug('Debug Log for Document_Master__c'+doc.Document_Master__r.Name);
                System.debug('Debug Log for Document_Master__c'+doc.Contact_Name__c);*/

                if(String.isNotBlank(doc.Contact_Name__c)) {
                    if(!mapContactNametoDocChecklist.containsKey(doc.Contact_Name__c)) {
                        mapContactNametoDocChecklist.put(doc.Contact_Name__c,new List<Document_Checklist__c>());
                    }
                    mapContactNametoDocChecklist.get(doc.Contact_Name__c).add(doc);
                }
                else {
                    if(!mapContactNametoDocChecklist.containsKey('Not Specified')) {
                        mapContactNametoDocChecklist.put('Not Specified',new List<Document_Checklist__c>());
                    }
                    mapContactNametoDocChecklist.get('Not Specified').add(doc);
                }
            }
            for(String strContactName : mapContactNametoDocChecklist.keySet()) {
                lstDocumentWrapper.add(new DocumentListWrapper(strContactName, mapContactNametoDocChecklist.get(strContactName)));
            }
        } 
        System.debug('Debug Log for lstDocumentWrapper'+lstDocumentWrapper);   
        //For Testing Purpose 
        for(DocumentListWrapper objDocumentListWrapper : lstDocumentWrapper) {
            System.debug('Key:'+objDocumentListWrapper.strContactName);
            System.debug('Value:'+objDocumentListWrapper.lstDocumentCheckList);
        }
        //return returnList;
        return lstDocumentWrapper;
    }


    // method for fetch picklist values dynamic  
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List < String > getselectOptions(sObject objObject, string fld) {
        system.debug('objObject --->' + objObject);
        system.debug('fld --->' + fld);

        List < String > allOpts = new list < String > ();
        // Get the object type of the SObject.
        Schema.sObjectType objType = objObject.getSObjectType();

        // Describe the SObject using its object type.
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objDescribe = objType.getDescribe();

        // Get a map of fields for the SObject
        map < String, Schema.SObjectField > fieldMap = objDescribe.fields.getMap();

        // Get the list of picklist values for this field.
        list < Schema.PicklistEntry > values =
            fieldMap.get(fld).getDescribe().getPickListValues();

        // Add these values to the selectoption list.
        for (Schema.PicklistEntry a: values) {
            allOpts.add(a.getValue());
        }
        system.debug('allOpts ---->' + allOpts);
        allOpts.sort();
        return allOpts;
    }



    @AuraEnabled
    public static list<Attachment> getAttachment(Id parentId)
    {
        return [SELECT ParentId, Name, Id, ContentType, BodyLength FROM Attachment where ParentId =: parentId];
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List <DocumentListWrapper> saveLoan(List <DocumentListWrapper> listOfDoc) {
        System.debug('list-->'+listOfDoc.size());
        System.debug('Debug Log for param list'+listOfDoc);
        List<Document_Checklist__c> lstDocchkLst = new List<Document_Checklist__c>();
        if(!listOfDoc.isEmpty()) {
            for(DocumentListWrapper objDocumentListWrapper : listOfDoc) {
                //lstDocchkLst.addAll(objDocumentListWrapper.lstDocumentCheckList);
                system.debug(objDocumentListWrapper.lstDocumentCheckList);
            }
        }
        System.debug('Debug Log for lstDocchkLst'+lstDocchkLst);
        if(!lstDocchkLst.isEmpty()) {
            Database.Saveresult[] updateList = Database.update(lstDocchkLst,false);
            for (Database.SaveResult sr : updateList) {
                if (sr.isSuccess()) {
                    // Operation was successful, so get the ID of the record that was processed
                    System.debug('Successfully updated Document Checklist. Record ID: ' + sr.getId());
                }
                else {
                    // Operation failed, so get all errors                
                    for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
                        System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
                        System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
                        System.debug('Fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return listOfDoc;
        //return null;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<ID> queryAttachments (Id propertyId) {
        List<ContentDocumentLink> links;
        List<ContentVersion> lstContentVersion;
        Set<Id> setContentVersionId = new Set<Id>();
        String objectAPIName = '';
        String keyPrefix = '';
        System.debug('Debug Log for propertyId'+propertyId);
        keyPrefix = String.valueOf(propertyId).substring(0,3);
        for( Schema.SObjectType obj : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values() ){
             String prefix = obj.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();
              if(prefix == keyPrefix){
                        objectAPIName = obj.getDescribe().getName();
                        break;
               }
        }
        System.debug('Debug Log for objectAPIName:'+objectAPIName);
        if(String.isNotBlank(objectAPIName)) {
            if(objectAPIName == 'Document_Checklist__c') {
                links = [select id, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId=:propertyId];
                System.debug('Debug Log for links'+links.size());
                System.debug('Debug Log for links'+links);

                if (links.isEmpty()) {
                    return null;
                }

                Set<Id> contentIds = new Set<Id>();

                for (ContentDocumentLink link :links) {
                    contentIds.add(link.ContentDocumentId);
                }
                System.debug('Debug Log for contentIds'+contentIds);
                /*
                lstContentVersion = [SELECT Id, Title FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId IN :contentIds AND IsLatest=true];
                System.debug('Debug Log for lstContentVersion'+lstContentVersion);

                if(!lstContentVersion.isEmpty()) {
                    for(ContentVersion objContentVersion : lstContentVersion) {
                        setContentVersionId.add(objContentVersion.Id);
                    }
                }
                System.debug('Debug Log for setContentVersionId'+setContentVersionId);
                */
                List<Id> lstsettoList = new List<Id>(contentIds);            
                return lstsettoList;
            }

            else if(objectAPIName == 'Loan_Application__c') {
                List<Document_Checklist__c> lstDocumentList = [SELECT Id FROM Document_Checklist__c WHERE Loan_Applications__c =: propertyId];
                Set<Id> setDocumentListIds = new Set<Id>();
                System.debug('Debug Log for lstDocumentList'+lstDocumentList.size());
                if(!lstDocumentList.isEmpty()) {
                    for(Document_Checklist__c objDC : lstDocumentList) {
                        setDocumentListIds.add(objDC.Id);
                    }
                }
                System.debug('Debug Log for setDocumentListIds'+setDocumentListIds.size());
                if(!setDocumentListIds.isEmpty()) {
                    links = [select id, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId IN:setDocumentListIds];

                    if (links.isEmpty()) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    Set<Id> contentIds = new Set<Id>();

                    for (ContentDocumentLink link :links) {
                        contentIds.add(link.ContentDocumentId);
                    }
                    System.debug('Debug Log for contentIds'+contentIds);
                    List<Id> lstsettoList1 = new List<Id>(contentIds);            
                    return lstsettoList1;

                    //return [SELECT Id, Title FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId IN :contentIds AND IsLatest=true];
                }
            }

        }
        return new List<Id>();
    }

    public class DocumentListWrapper {
        @AuraEnabled public String strContactName;
        @AuraEnabled public List<Document_Checklist__c> lstDocumentCheckList;

        public DocumentListWrapper(String paramContactName, List<Document_Checklist__c> paramListDocChkLst) {
            this.strContactName = paramContactName;
            this.lstDocumentCheckList = paramListDocChkLst;
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of Exception :

[image]

The actual text of the debugged list is as follows (saveLoan method in Apex Class) :

```
(
    {   
        lstDocumentCheckList=[{Id=a0Cp0000005z40BEAQ, Status__c=Uploaded, Scan_Check_Completed__c=true, Screened__c=false, Sampled__c=false}, {Id=a0Cp0000005z40CEAQ, Status__c=Uploaded, Scan_Check_Completed__c=true, Screened__c=false, Sampled__c=false}, {Id=a0Cp0000005z40DEAQ, Status__c=Received, Scan_Check_Completed__c=true, Screened__c=false, Sampled__c=false}, {Id=a0Cp0000005z40EEAQ, Status__c=Received, Scan_Check_Completed__c=true, Screened__c=false, Sampled__c=false}, {Id=a0Cp0000005z40FEAQ, Status__c=Received, Scan_Check_Completed__c=true, Screened__c=false, Sampled__c=false}], 
        strContactName=Not Specified
    }, 
    {
        lstDocumentCheckList=[{Id=a0Cp0000005z43VEAQ, Contact_Name__c=Anil Suresh, Status__c=Received, Scan_Check_Completed__c=true, Screened__c=false, Sampled__c=false}, {Id=a0Cp0000005z43ZEAQ, Contact_Name__c=Anil Suresh, Status__c=Received, Scan_Check_Completed__c=true, Screened__c=false, Sampled__c=false}, {Id=a0Cp0000005z43YEAQ, Contact_Name__c=Anil Suresh, Status__c=Received, Scan_Check_Completed__c=true, Screened__c=false, Sampled__c=false}, {Id=a0Cp0000005z43XEAQ, Contact_Name__c=Anil Suresh, Status__c=Received, Scan_Check_Completed__c=true, Screened__c=false, Sampled__c=false}, {Id=a0Cp0000005z43WEAQ, Contact_Name__c=Anil Suresh, Status__c=Received, Scan_Check_Completed__c=true, Screened__c=false, Sampled__c=false}], 
        strContactName=Anil Suresh
    }, 
    {
        lstDocumentCheckList=[{Id=a0Cp0000005z40GEAQ, Contact_Name__c=Turkish Pandey, Status__c=Received, Scan_Check_Completed__c=true, Screened__c=false, Sampled__c=false}, {Id=a0Cp0000005z40HEAQ, Contact_Name__c=Turkish Pandey, Status__c=Received, Scan_Check_Completed__c=true, Screened__c=false, Sampled__c=false}, {Id=a0Cp0000005z40IEAQ, Contact_Name__c=Turkish Pandey, Status__c=Received, Scan_Check_Completed__c=true, Screened__c=false, Sampled__c=false}, {Id=a0Cp0000005z40JEAQ, Contact_Name__c=Turkish Pandey, Status__c=Received, Scan_Check_Completed__c=true, Screened__c=false, Sampled__c=false}], 
        strContactName=Turkish Pandey}
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to locate the issue and get it fixed.

Issue Description : The Unexpected Exception was coming as soon as we were trying to process the list, i.e. checking the list size using isEmpty(), and doing a for loop.

Also, on debugging the list, it can be clearly observed that it was in a JSON Format, because in lightning component js controller, it was controlled as a JSON.

So, I passed the entire JSON from component, but this time, I caught it in the form of a string parameter for the save function in apex class.

Later I deserialized this JSON String to obtain pure list of wrapper class, which was easily processed and update logic followed.

The final method looks like this :

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static List <DocumentListWrapper> saveLoan(String paramJSONList) {
        System.debug('Debug Log for param list'+paramJSONList);
        List<Document_Checklist__c> lstDocchkLst = new List<Document_Checklist__c>();
        List<DocumentListWrapper> lstSerializedWrapper = (List<DocumentListWrapper>)JSON.deserialize(paramJSONList,List<DocumentListWrapper>.class);
        System.debug('Debug Log for deserialized List'+lstSerializedWrapper.size());
        System.debug('Debug Log for deserialized List'+lstSerializedWrapper);
        if(!lstSerializedWrapper.isEmpty()) {
            for(DocumentListWrapper objDocumentListWrapper : lstSerializedWrapper) {
                lstDocchkLst.addAll(objDocumentListWrapper.lstDocumentCheckList);
                system.debug(objDocumentListWrapper.lstDocumentCheckList);
            }
        }
        System.debug('Debug Log for lstDocchkLst'+lstDocchkLst);
        if(!lstDocchkLst.isEmpty()) {
            Database.Saveresult[] updateList = Database.update(lstDocchkLst,false);
            for (Database.SaveResult sr : updateList) {
                if (sr.isSuccess()) {
                    // Operation was successful, so get the ID of the record that was processed
                    System.debug('Successfully updated Document Checklist. Record ID: ' + sr.getId());
                }
                else {
                    // Operation failed, so get all errors                
                    for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
                        System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
                        System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
                        System.debug('Fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return lstSerializedWrapper;
    }
```